# Block access to sitemap.php but allow sitemap.xml

Tags: php, .htaccess, sitemap

I have a sitemap.php file in the news folder, where I dynamically create a sitemap based on the entries which I have in my database. I also have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

So the link can look like this: domain.com/news/sitemap.xml. It's working, but my question is: How can I block access to the `sitemap.php` file in .htaccess, so as not to give unnecessary information to others?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.php$ /sitemap.xml [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [NC,END]
```

It blocks the file from being visited and sends a 403 forbidden to the client. I am not 100% sure if it works with the other rewriterule, but just try it and let me know.

Comment: Unfortunetely, it's showing 403 also for sitemap.xml

Comment: Updated my answer, could you try this one?

Comment: Almost, when I type sitemap.php it's redirecting to .xml, but I want to show 404 error

Answer (score 0):

When the request is sent to a sitemap PHP file, redirect to the XML file.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^sitemap.php$ sitemap.xml
```

Comment: The sitemap.php file is still available, I want the sitemap.php file to show a 404 error